# index a hashtable when using object as key in python

Tags: python, hash, hashtable

so I have those two classes "key" and "value" and the idea is to create a hashtable out of them.

```
class key:
        num_master = -1
        num_slave = -1
        width = -1
        num_pipeline = -1
        diff_clock_master = -1
        diff_clock_slave = -1

        def __init__(self,m,s,w,p,dm,ds):
                self.num_master = m
                self.num_slave = s
                self.width = w
                self.num_pipeline = p
                self.diff_clock_master = dm
                self.diff_clock_slave = ds

        def __hash__(self):
                return hash((self.num_master,self.num_slave,self.width,self.num_pipeline,self.diff_clock_master,self.diff_clock_slave))

        def __eq__(self,other):
                return (self.num_master,self.num_slave,self.width,self.num_pipeline,self.diff_clock_master,self.diff_clock_slave) == (other.num_master,other.num_slave,other.width,other.num_pipeline,other.diff_clock_master,other.diff_clock_slave)   

class value:
        alms = -1
        brams = -1
        labs = -1
        freq = -1
        power = -1

        def __init__(self,a,b,l,f,p):
                self.alms = a
                self.brams = b
                self.labs = l
                self.freq = f
                self.power = p
```

So I populate the hash table as follows:

```
def parsify(report_name):
    report = open(report_name,'r')
    for line in report:

                #split line
                part_list = line.split()

                newkey = key(part_list[0],part_list[1],part_list[2],part_list[3],part_list[4],part_list[5])
                newvalue = value(part_list[6],part_list[7],part_list[8],part_list[9],part_list[10])
                hash_table[newkey]=newvalue

                return hash_table
```

then I try to index into the hash table like this:

```
#test
hash_table = parsify('report.txt')

qkey = key(1,1,16,0,0,0)
print hash_table[qkey].alms
```

but it doesn't work. How can I index into this hash table and how can I make this easier?

and here's a sample report.txt:

```
1   1   16  0   0   0   102.0   0.0 10.2    300.75  1.36    m1_s1_w16_p0_dcm0_dcs0_traffic_0_----->_m1_s1_w16_p0_dcm0_dcs0_traffic_0
1   1   16  1   0   0   102.0   0.0 10.2    300.75  1.36    m1_s1_w16_p1_dcm0_dcs0_traffic_0_----->_m1_s1_w16_p1_dcm0_dcs0_traffic_0
1   1   16  2   0   0   102.0   0.0 10.2    300.75  1.36    m1_s1_w16_p2_dcm0_dcs0_traffic_0_----->_m1_s1_w16_p2_dcm0_dcs0_traffic_0
1   1   16  3   0   0   166.0   0.0 16.6    303.03  2.02    m1_s1_w16_p3_dcm0_dcs0_traffic_0_----->_m1_s1_w16_p3_dcm0_dcs0_traffic_0
```

Comment: It works for me using your dummy values (5, 3, 16, 0, 0, 0).  Are you sure that there is actually a key with those values inside "report.txt"?  Can you provide a self-contained example with sample data illustrating the problem?

Comment: yeah I am sure this value exists, a very simple file would just look like this: (I'll add it to the question)

Comment: First of all, you *do not* need the funny variables in the beginning of the class. These are not "default values", but rather class variables. Changing one will change it for *all* instances. If you want default values, use def __init__(self, a=-1, b=-1) and so on.

Comment: Anyway, instead of these classes, you can use collections.namedtuple to return a simple hashable type.

Comment: the '-1's are just for debug, they don't really matter. I'm interested in how I can make it work with objects?

Comment: This doesn't look like code you're actually running.  You wrote `def_parsify` instead of `def parsify`.  Also, you pass in the filename "report.txt", but then you iterate over it as if it were the actual file.  This would give an IndexError since there wouldn't be enough elements in the split.  Please post the code you're actually using.

Comment: It is the code I'm running, these were just typos and I corrected them now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue you're having is that you building your dictionary with strings in the `key` instances. Then when you go to look up an item, you're using integers in the `key` instance. `"0"` is not equal to `0` in Python, so your lookup is failing.

Instead of `qkey = key(1,1,16,0,0,0)`, try using `qkey = key("1","1","16","0","0","0")` in your test code.

Or alternatively, you might want to convert the strings to integers and floating point values when you create the `key`s and `value`s in the first place:

```
newkey = key(*map(int, part_list[:6]))         # first six values are ints
newvalue = value(*map(float, part_list[6:11])) # next five are floats
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this easier by using tuples for your dictionary keys instead of a custom class.  For example, since you create your key thus:

```
key(1,1,16,0,0,0)
```

you may as well use a simple tuple here

```
(1,1,16,0,0,0)
```

and when reading the data too:

```
tuple(part_list[:6])
```

Tuples make good keys for dictionaries and then you don't need to worry about classes. The values could logically be stored as tuples too. Or do you have a reason for requiring the more complicated structure?

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question posed. You shouldn't post a comment as an answer. I realize you don't have enough rep to comment yet, but that's no excuse.

Comment: I was attempting to answer the "how can I make this easier" part of the question.